# How do C# decompiler work without PDB files?

Tags: c#, .net, security, reverse-engineering, pdb-files

I know from [John Robbins blog](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx) that `.NET PDB` files contain the source file names, line numbers and the local variable names. But reverse-engineering softwares like `ILSpy`, or `.Net Reflector` can still pretty much figure out most of the code.

Code flow is easier to obtain. But how do these software extract data like function names, variable names ?

Comment: You can open the .exe in a text editor to see what is available as plain text.

Comment: You should read the Richter's book "CLR via C#" 4th edition, in particular, Part 1, ch. 2.

Comment: Related question with more references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918270/how-does-c-sharp-decompiler-work?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

> Code flow is easier to obtain. But how do these software extract data like function names, variable names ?

Assemblies contain such information in Metadata. As explained in the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf),

> New types—value types and reference types—are introduced into the CTS (Common Type System) via type declarations expressed in **metadata**. In addition, metadata is a structured way to represent all information that the CLI (Common Language Infrastructure) uses to locate and load classes, lay out instances in memory, resolve method invocations, translate CIL (Common Intermediate Language) to native code, enforce security, and set up runtime context boundaries.

Also, it is important to note that this information is not only accessible to these "reverse-engineering" tools, but also to your C# (or VB) code via [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). For example, knowing the names of methods in given type is possible through reflection because it is part of metadata.

Here's an excerpt from the [.Net Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/metadata-and-self-describing-components) which explains what is included in Metadata:

> Metadata describes every type and member defined in your code in a
>   language-neutral manner. Metadata stores the following information:
>
> - Description of the assembly.
>
>   - Identity (name, version, culture, public key).
>   - The types that are exported.
>   - Other assemblies that this assembly depends on.
>   - Security permissions needed to run.
> - Description of types.
>
>   - Name, visibility, base class, and interfaces implemented.
>   - Members (methods, fields, properties, events, nested types).
> - Attributes.
>
>   - Additional descriptive elements that modify types and members.

Now that doesn't necessarily include local variable names, which are often not reverse-engineered correctly by such tools.

Comment: In addition to this, the IL format specification is open and standardized (https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), so it's very accessible to "reverse-engineer" (parse) by external tools, even if those tools are not .NET-based themselves.

Comment: Thanks @Paul-Jan. I was completely unaware of the spec. I will try and include relevant information in my answer.